# How can I get Controls/UIElements from a TabItem itself in a TabItem or TabControl using wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have a tabcontrol using MVVM Wpf c#. Now, I want to default focus control when active tabitem but it doesnot lost focus when move tab.
I used live visual tree but not active because paramater is viewmodel. I have used FocusManger get focus for control therefore I need get controls/UI from a tabItem itself.

Can you help me?Thanks

Comment: Use proper english which everyone can understand, and try to describe your problem using proper code snippet / figures etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get all the logical children recursively:

```
private void GetAllChildren(DependencyObject parent, List<DependencyObject> allChildren)
{
    var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);

    foreach (var child in children.OfType<DependencyObject>())
    {
        allChildren.Add(child);
        GetAllChildren(child, allChildren);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will test. Thank you